# List apps that are downloaded to my phone

Tags: ios, iphone

How do I know what apps are downloaded to my iPhone 4?

Comment: Please use tags relevant to the content of the question. For more information on tags, see [What are tags, and how should I use them?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 3):

Depending on which version of iOS you are using there is different ways to check that.
If you are using a new version of iOS like 7 or 8 then you can do the following or something similar.

1. Open the "Settings" app.
2. Go to General -> Usage -> Manage Storage (under Storage).
3. Now you should soon see a list of apps installed on your iPhone.

Remember that this is only applicable for newer versions of iOS. Also, between the versions the steps can differ a bit but it is similar. Check under "General" in Settings and look carefully for something like "Usage" or "Storage".

Answer (score 0):

Open Spotlight by pulling down on the home screen, then search for ".".
The first category is Applications, providing a list of applications that are installed.

Comment: That does not work. At least not on iOS 8.

Comment: @Dempa Works fine for me on iOS 8.3 on iPhone, iOS 8.2 on iPhone and iOS 7.1.3 on iPad. Make sure you're searching for just the character `.` and have Applications selected in Spotlight settings.

Comment: I only see 9 of the applications and yes I have more than 9 apps installed (274). I am searching for just the 'dot' (.).